# Compare element in array to all previous element's of the array

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm looking for a way to compare an element in an array with all previous elements in the array -- as I've had no luck in doing so.

For example, if you have an array of size 10 and the current index is 4, you would compare a[4] to a[3],a[2],a[1],a[0] and then when you increment to 5 to compare a[5] to a[4],a[3],a[2],a[1],a[0] and so on and so forth.

Comment: I'd love to know specifically *why* you want to do this, lest you fall into the trap of the so-called [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You can use pythons [slice](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) notation, and do your compare on a[:index-1]

Comment: @CDspace I think you mean `a[:index]`

Comment: @NiklasB. No, in his example, he is comparing a[4] with a[3] and below, thus `index-1`, where index = 4

Comment: @CDspace: Have you read the link that you provided?

Comment: @NiklasB. Indeed, you are correct. I always have issues trying to get my indices correct.

Comment: @CDspace: As a rule of thumb, in `a[from:to]`, `to - from` is always the length of the slice. `from` is 0 by default, while that of `to` is `len(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if j==i:
            break
        if a[i] == a[j]:
            print "Same"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but, all you are trying to find the index of a value in a list, you can use the index method.

```
In [16]: li
Out[16]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [17]: li.index(5)
Out[17]: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if i != 0:
        el, prev = lst[i], lst[i-1]
        if el == prev: print "1"
        else: print "0"
```